# Yet another solution needed for binding button signals to slots in Qt

Tags: python, qt, lambda, signals, functools

I'm trying to develop a `Slicer` module in Python, using qt. I have a list of buttons (`QPushButton`) and I want each of their `"clicked"` signals to be bound to the same method but passing different arguments (that is just to know **what button was pressed**).

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
def createButtons(self):
  for object in self.myList:
    button = qt.QPushButton(object.name)
    button.clicked.connect(self.myMethod(object.name)) # I know this is not valid

def myMethod(self, name):
  print name, 'was pressed.'
```

I already used all the three ways suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966731/pyside-pyqt-simple-way-to-bind-multiple-buttons-that-shares-the-same-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893876/pyqt-and-qsignalmapper-lambdas-multiple-signals-single-slot), but I have different problems:

- The `QSignalMapper` solution is a mess because I can't use PyQt/PySide.
- The lambda solution makes my code print always the text of the last button, no matter which one is pressed. I wrote something like:

  ```
  button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.myMethod(object.name))
  ```
- The partial solution was implemented as:

  ```
  button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.myMethod, object.name))
  ```

  But I got the following error:

  ```
  TypeError: myMethod() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
  ```

Right now I'm using a horrible list of different written methods, so my ugly solution, which works, is:

```
button.clicked.connect(self.myButtonMethods[self.myList.index(object)])
```

I hope my question hasn't been asked before and that you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of PyQT are you using? The `partial` code you've showed looks right - can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I'm actually using `qt 4.8.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/), pyQT after 4.5 introduced a new API

try this:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), functools.partial(self.myMethod, object.name) )
```