# PyQt: Getting which button called a specific function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have made a Multi-Page application in PyQt, Generally a Quiz game.

So now whenever user makes mistake or answers the question correctly, It calls correct/incorrect function.

---

Incorrect answer function:

```
def incorrect(self):
    self.pic3.hide()
    self.que1.hide()
    self.answ.hide()
    self.answ1.hide()
    self.answ2.hide()
    self.pic4.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
    self.pic4.show()
    self.goback.show() 
    self.cont = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    self.cont.setObjectName('cont')
    self.cont.setStyleSheet("#cont {background-image: url(':/images/Continue.png'); border: none; }"
    "#cont:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Continue1.png'); }"
    "#cont:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Continue2.png'); }")
    self.cont.setGeometry(980, 610, 300, 300)
    self.cont.clicked.connect(self.question2)
    self.cont.show()
    self.heart2.hide()
    #self.heart1.hide()
    if ( self.heart2.isHidden() and self.heart1.isHidden() ):
        gameover()
    else:
        pass
```

So i'm gonna make multiple "cont" widgets in this function, The purpose of that is because i want it to continue to specific question (If user failed or succeed at **question 1**, it should continue to **question 2**).

But for that, there should be a code that determines whether incorrect answer function is called from **button1** or **button2**, both buttons connect to same slot when clicked, if it is called from **button1**, it will show cont pushbutton, which displays **question2** widgets when clicked (Question2 page).

But if its called from **button2**, it will show cont2 pushbutton, which will display Question 3 page when clicked.

**It should look something like this in code**:

```
if self.connected from button1:
   cont.show()
if self.connected from button2:
   cont2.show()
else:
    pass
```

## Picture example:

[image]

Comment: How is this not a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893876/pyqt-and-qsignalmapper-lambdas-multiple-signals-single-slot or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966731/pyside-pyqt-simple-way-to-bind-multiple-buttons-that-shares-the-same-function

Comment: @neuronet This is not a "dupe", these questions were hard to understand since they were oriented in specific objective of some problem, I just made it more general and easily understandable for me and the reader, using pictures, example codes and general question which will be useful for others.

Comment: Hmmm...not convinced. Yours actually seems very specific to the problem you are working on, while those seem to get to the general point succinctly. I'm having trouble seeing what is unique here. Especially given that the answer you accepted is basically identical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your buttons are named `self.button1` and `self.button2`, you could bind your event handler using [partially bound functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html):

```
from functools import partial
self.button1.clicked.connect(partial(self.question, self.button1))
self.button2.clicked.connect(partial(self.question, self.button2))
```

Then take another parameter in your `question` method, i.e.

```
def question(self, btn):
     if btn == self.button1:
         # Button 1 was clicked
     elif btn == self.button2:
         # Button 2 was clicked
```

Comment: It worked! but it kept giving this error in console `TypeError: incorrect() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` but i defined incorrect like this: `def incorrect(self, sendercheck):`

Comment: In addition to partial functions, and the sender function, you can also use `QSignalMapper` which is very convenient....As discussed at the putative duplicates linked in comments.

Answer (score 8):

Use `sender()` function to get a QObject that has sent the signal:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked) # connect signal to slot

        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()  # This is what you need
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
```

Comment: Yes but how do i include this in boolean? So it determines whether its from btn_1 or btn_2.

Comment: Assuming you have your button objects: `(sender == my_button)`